# Add external libraries to Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, libraries

I am trying to add an external library (PHP Simple DOM Parser, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) to a Symfony2 project. I took a tutorial that explains how to include third party libraries to Symfony2 http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2.

I set up a class file like:

```
# vendor/phpsimpledom/lib/Phpsimpledom/simple_html_dom.php

require_once __DIR__.'/src/simple_html_dom.php';

class Phpsimpledom_Phpsimpledom extends simple_html_dom_node {
}
```

and registered my class in my Autoloader (autoload.php):

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
...
'Phpsimpledom' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/phpsimpledom/lib/',
...
),));
```

I am trying to call:

```
$phpsimpledom = new \Phpsimpledom();
```

but this throughs me an error (Fatal error: Class 'simple_html_dom_node' not found).

However: The main file of the library (simple_html_dom.php) consists of functions that do not belong to a class.

When I try to use the file directly, it also doesn't work:

```
    $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
...
'Phpsimpledom' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/phpsimpledom/lib/Phpsimpledom/src/simple_html_dom.php',
...
),));
```

Any hints?

THANKS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to register a namespace but your class has no namespace. Try adding a namespace to it or use RegisterPrefixes().

BTW: did you know that one of the Symfony components is basically doing the same thing as php simpledom? It's called DomCrawler and it has a support for both xpath and CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Symfony2 but as i can see, you are not respecting the PSR for autoloader.

I'm presumable thinking you should do:

```php
# /vendor/phpsimpledom/lib/Phpsimpledom/Phpsimpledom.php

require_once __DIR__.'/src/simple_html_dom.php';

class Phpsimpledom_Phpsimpledom extends simple_html_dom_node {

}
```

Note that the correct filename would be `/vendor/phpsimpledom/lib/Phpsimpledom/Phpsimpledom.php` as the call must include the namespace to work.

Hope it works now.