# Symfony 2.4 and Google Drive Integration

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, symfony-2.4

i am trying to integrate the #google-drive-sdk in my project symfony 2.4 where i wish to use this SDK to attach docs and edit it in my site ( if have other tips or idea i'm waiting for), and i am looking for a full  example witch give a hole idea.
i found this subject [Symfony2 and Google API integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457987/including-files-with-symfony2) but it is looked missing code.
so, if there is no samples you may guide me to resolve it.
thanks for all.

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm interstellare in the topic, too: did you find any good examples of this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Happyr/GoogleApiBundle?

Comment: And also maybe here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/php